# When use cmd line to “mkdir x”, access denied by windows

Tags: windows, cmd

When using command line to `mkdir x`, access denied by Windows. The command line of Windows Version: 6.1.7601.

However When i type: `mkdir a` or `mkdir b`  ...is successful.

Is `x` or `X` a special folder for command line?

Comment: The directory "X" or "x" is surely not exist when i type the command.and i can create directory "x" or "X" by using right click mouse in windows.<br/> <br/>

Comment: Your batch might use different encodings than the explorer. I assume you use Chinese characters in the name X ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running cmd as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

I've know the reason.
Because trend tech's anti-virus program forbid me to create directory named "x" or "X". It's very ridiculous.